# Bash script help

Tags: apt

The --print-uris in apt will print the entire output along with the urls to a specified txt file. I need a command which will only select the packges to be installed from the output of print uris and redirect them to a file. As you might have guessed i m trying to create a script.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the exact command you are talking about?

Comment: As jobin said, post the command your tried.

Comment: i use apt-get --print-uris .it prints everyting you see when you run apt-get install

Answer (score 0):

Mowiewowie, another proof of apt supercow ability!! Maybe this file, called `supercow`, helps:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# exactly one argument
[[ $# -ne 1 ]] && echo "Usage: $( basename $0 ) PACKAGE" && exit 1

PACKAGE_DIRECTORY=$( mktemp -d )    # Target directory
PACKAGE_LOGFILE=$( mktemp )         # Target file
cd $PACKAGE_DIRECTORY || exit 1     # Exit if directory does not exist
apt_out_all=$(( apt-get --print-uris --yes install $1 ) 2>&1 )

apt_out_check=$( echo $apt_out_all | sed s/^.*information...\ // )

# error checks
if ! [[ $( echo $apt_out_check | grep "packages will be installed" ) ]]
then
    echo -n "ERROR: "

    if   [[ "${apt_out_check%% *}" == "E:" ]]
        then echo "Unable to locate package $1."

    elif [[ "${apt_out_check%% *}" == "$1" ]]
        then echo "$1 already installed." # look at /var/cache/apt/archives

    # other, eg: Package solid is not available, but is referred to ...
    else echo "${apt_out_check}"
    fi
    exit 1
fi

# loop through all lines: tee to file if package, wget uri if not empty
for i in $apt_out_all ; do
    uri=$(  echo $i | tee >(grep ".deb$" >> $PACKAGE_LOGFILE) \
                    | grep "^'http" | sed -e s/^\'// -e s/\'$// )
    [[ $uri ]] && if ! wget $uri ; then
                echo "ERROR: wget failed" ; exit 1 ; fi
done

echo "Here is the content of the logfile:" ; cat $PACKAGE_LOGFILE
echo -e "\nHere is the content of the directory:" ; ls $PACKAGE_DIRECTORY
```

My first attempt was a big fail because there was neither a check for mad user input nor if the package is already installed. Moreover, it appeared that if eg. `gcc` is already installed drops an error string and for instance `geany` just an empty line. So i would still use it with healthy suspicion although this attempt feels way more solid. I also erased double-checks, etc.

Example: `$ bash supercow kobodeluxe`

```
#... wget messages

Here is the content of the logfile:
kobodeluxe-data_0.5.1-6_all.deb
kobodeluxe_0.5.1-6_amd64.deb

Here is the content of the directory:
kobodeluxe_0.5.1-6_amd64.deb  kobodeluxe-data_0.5.1-6_all.deb
```

Example: `$ bash supercow bash`

```
bash already installed.
```

Example: `$ bash supercow windows3.11`

```
Unable to locate package windows3.11.
```

Example: `$bash supercow solid`

```
ERROR: Package solid is not available, but is referred to by another package.
#...
```

Hopefully this helps!

EDIT TO QUESTION: 
Then replace `grep ".deb$" >> $PACKAGE_LOGFILE` inside brackets with `grep ".deb$" | sed s/_.*// >> $PACKAGE_LOGFILE` because i don't know an official package that contains an underscore unless I am mistaken.

Comment: I was looking for something different though.Wanted to create a removal scripy but apt doesnt accept package versions along with package name as parameters.

Comment: i was thinkking about a for loop that would go through all characters in --print-uris output and select only package s names ignoring there  versions. Example kobodeluxe_0.5.1-6_amd64.deb should be kobodeluxe as apt will not  baccept the version name that comes after kobodeluxe